# adding empty Route table to a Subnet

Tags: azure, routes, policy, azure-virtual-network, subnet

Working on a policy to deny the creation of a subnet on a Vnet when a empty(with 0 routes) route table is attached. In azure, routes can only be created after creating a route table.

```
<code>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a policy to deny the creation when a route table is not assigned to subnet, would like to improve the policy by making sure route table have atleast one UDR.

The below policy will `deny` the subnet creation if a subnet does not have a route table assigned, or if a subnet has a route table assigned but no routes are defined in that route table.

Here is the updated policy.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
              "field": "type"
            },
            {
              "exists": "false",
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.id"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.routes",
              "exists": "false"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

The policy denies subnet creation when I try to create a subnet with a route table, but the assigned route table has no defined routes (UDRs) as shown below.

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: This policy blocks adding route tables with and without routes, which is not the use case.

Comment: The above policy will check only routetable and Routes inside route table, if there is no route table and routes inside routetable in Subnet, the policy will block the subnet creation..

Comment: You want to deny subnet creation when a route table is assigned to it and that assigned route table has no defined routes?

Comment: Deny the subnet creation when route table is not attached to it(which is working with the policy I have) and also deny the creation if route table have empty routes.

Which means attach a route table with routes present in order to add a subnet on VN.

Comment: This is the condition to check Routes in route table.:"allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.routes",
              "exists": "false"
            }
          ]
what is the issue with my policy, I'm done the testing and added pic also for your reference.

Comment: condition 1: create subnet without adding route table = Deny
condition 2: create subnet with adding route table with route present = Allow 
condition 3: create subnet with adding route table with 0 routes = Deny

Condition 2 is also denied for me. Can you check on your end please